# Python can't find module 'dotenv'?

Tags: python, pip, python-dotenv

when I try importing load_dotenv from dotenv I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'`

Tho I already installed dotenv with `py -m pip install python-dotenv`

If I try running that command again I simply get
`Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv in c:\users\[my name]\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (0.19.2)`

So it should be installed, shouldn't it?
Have no idea what could be the issue here.

Comment: Can you check where it is installed it may possible it is installed outside of your virtual env. Try these steps to see if it helps :

pip uninstall dotenv

pip uninstall python-dotenv

pip install python-dotenv

Comment: The Python interpreter you used to run your app/script should be the same Python interpreter where you installed your package. If you used `py -m pip install` to install dotenv, then use the same `py` to run your app. If you run your app inside a virtual env, then you need to install the package inside the same virtual env.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)

Comment: I literally had this problem for multiple hours and managed to fix it five minutes after posting this, tho I don't really know how.
I saw an unrelated post discussing something with the Anaconda Prompt so I just decided to try and install it there again.
I ran ``` pip install python-dotenv[cli]``` in the powershell prompt and my problem got fixed.
Can someone explain what happened? Still new to programming